Flutter - StreamBuilder
I'm working on a Flutter app and I'm encountering an issue with the StreamBuilder widget. I'm using StreamBuilder to display a list of posts, and I have a button to open the comment page for each post. When I switch from the home page to the comment page using Navigator.of(context).push(), the StreamBuilder on the home page rebuilds. As a result, when I return to the home page from the comment page, the list of posts is reset and I'm back to the first post.
I added a print statement to the StreamBuilder to see if it rebuilds, and it does while I'm on the comment page.
To make it easier to understand, I've created a video to illustrate the issue here.
I have already reviewed other questions related to this issue, but I have not found anything that has helped me.
Sure, here is the code for my entire StreamBuilder:
StreamBuilder(
  // StreamBuilder de refresh
  stream: Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).refreshStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    print("rebuild");
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      _uniqueKey = UniqueKey().toString();
    }
    return StreamBuilder(
      key: Key(_uniqueKey),
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          // Chargement ...
          return const CupertinoActivityIndicator(
            radius: 25,
          );
        }

        if (snapshot.data!["followedPostsOnly"]) {
          // Afficher les posts des utilisateurs suivis uniquement
          if (snapshot.data!["followedAccounts"] == null ||
              snapshot.data!["followedAccounts"] == [] ||
              snapshot.data!["followedAccounts"].isEmpty) {
            // Aucun compte suivis = Aucun post à afficher
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Aucun compte suivi",
                    style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Gap(30),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Pour afficher les posts de tous les utilisateurs de l'application, rendez-vous dans les réglages.",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }

          // Afficher les posts
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("Posts")
                .where("author", whereIn: snapshot.data!["followedAccounts"])
                .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                // Chargement ...
                return const CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                  radius: 25,
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                // Aucun post
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Aucun post",
                    style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  // Message plus de posts (en dessous des tous les posts ce qui le rend visible seulement quand il n'y en a plus)
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                  .foregroundPost ==
                              null
                          ? "Plus de posts ..."
                          : "",
                      style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Posts
                  Stack(
                    children: List.generate(
                      snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      (index) {
                        return MySimplePost(
                          postID: snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference.id,
                          stackIndex:
                              snapshot.data!.docs.length - 1 - index,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
        // Afficher les posts de tout le monde
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("Posts")
              .orderBy("timestamp", descending: false)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null ||
                snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty ||
                snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
              // Aucun post
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Aucun post",
                  style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
              (timeStamp) {
                Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).setLastPost(
                  snapshot.data!.docs.first.reference.id,
                );
              },
            );
            return Stack(
              children: [
                // Message plus de posts (en dessous des tous les posts ce qui le rend visible seulement quand il n'y en a plus)
                Center(
                  child: Consumer<MyProvider>(
                    builder: (context, provider, _) {
                      return Text(
                        provider.foregroundPost == null
                            ? "Plus de posts ..."
                            : "",
                        style: GoogleFonts.kanit(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),

                // Posts
                Stack(
                  children: List.generate(
                    snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    (index) {
                      return MySimplePost(
                        postID: snapshot.data!.docs[index].reference.id,
                        stackIndex:
                            snapshot.data!.docs.length - 1 - index,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  },
)

NOTE: Please avoid looking at the details in the comment page. I am aware that there is an issue while posting a comment, but I will fix it later.
If anyone needs more details about my code, use-case, or anything else, please post a comment and I'll respond quickly. I welcome any advice as I'm a beginner in development and looking to improve. Feel free to comment on anything in my code, even if it's not related to my current issue.
Thanks.

You are probably instantiating the stream in an inefficient way.
Please take a look at this detailed Post on how to do it within the initState

I checked the post. I replaced all of my StreamBuilders with FutureBuilders and initiated their Future in initState. As a result, I changed from a StatelessWidget to a StatefulWidget. However, even with these changes, I'm encountering the same issue...
